# mysql connect to remote database

Tags: mysql

I wish to modify data on my website database and thought I could do it from the command line but it keeps failing.
For example:-

> website is myweb.co.uk
>   database is mydb
>   port 22

```
mysql -u myweb -hmyweb.mysql  -P22 -Dmydb
```

Presumably, I just need to get these three terms right and it should work

Comment: I think one form would be `mysql -u myweb -h 'remote server ip or name' -P 22  -D mydb -p 'password'` or `mysql -u username -h host -P 22 -p` and remote must accept remote access

Comment: The resolution will be very easy.  The problem with providing the resolution is that you didn't provide enough information.  Please  [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1095610/edit) and add the error output.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, port 22 is used for ssh, not mysql. In addition, its not common to run mysql visible on the internet.

But, if you do have ssh access, you can work around this, by tunneling mysql trough ssh.

In one terminal, run

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 example.com
```

where example.com is the remote ssh server. This creates a tunnel, between port 3306 locally, and on the remote end. This is encrypted and transported via ssh, so any secrets (passwords and queries) are encrypted while transported over the internet.

In another terminal, you will be able to run

```
mysql -h localhost --protocol=TCP -u username -p
```

`--protocol=TCP` is required, as by default mysql will connect to the socket connection on localhost, but this is unavailable, as mysql is not running locally. This connects to the ssh-tunnel set up previously.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I can connect with ssh in one terminal but from the second terminal I get:- ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user .  the command was:- mysql -h localhost --protocol=TCP -umyweb.co.uk -p

Comment: Sorry, the host shown in the error message was 'myweb.co.uk'@'localhost'

Comment: Did you enter a password?

Comment: Yes, but you're right because there are several passwords associated with the website, but I tried them all.

Comment: Use the same credentials as for MySQL in the application you have...

Comment: I am sure about the password for the database so that leaves the username that must be wrong.  I am using just myweb.co.uk for the username.  Also, when I run the command the response in instant, no hesitation.  Does that suggest a basic syntax failure?

Comment: I have just discovered that my web provider does not allow remote access although the php code sugested did work